# como poner valor 0 por defecto en dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

entonces el dropdown trae los siguientes valores

```
VALOR1
VALOR2
VALOR3
```

Quier que el combo traiga un valor por defecto para que me diga elija su opcion ejemplo:

```
-- SELECCIONE --
VALOR1
VALOR2
VALOR3
```

por que siempre me trae por defecto VALOR1

Controller

```
ViewBag.VBPais = new SelectList(db.Pais, "IdPais", "Nombre");
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownList("VBPais")
```

**Probando con SelectListItem**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intento de @Einer
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `db.Pais` es de tipo `SelectListItem`?

Comment: `db.Pais` es una tabla que la traigo de la base de datos.

Comment: Y que exactamente muestar el DropDownList? Como lo muestras en tu ejemplo?

Comment: me mustra el primer valor de mi tabla VALOR1

Comment: estas buscando algo como: @Html.DropDownList("VBPais", ViewBag.VBPais as SelectList, "--Seleccione uno--", new { @Class = "form-control" })  ???????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**POr experiencia propia te sugiero que siempre**

```
 @Html.DropDownList("IdPais", null, "Seleccione un país", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Eso es rodrigo pero recuerda que el cuarto parámetro de ese Helper es para los atribustos HTML pero por experiencia propia no siempre es new { class = "form-control" }, ¿Que pasaría si en vez de Bootstrap utilizo SemanticUI?

Comment: A los que tengan el mismo problema, deben comprender que para enlazar la `ViewBag` al método extendido `DropDownList` el primer parámetro debería ser `VBPais` y no `IdPais`. Asimismo, que el valor por defecto que tendría el primer `<option>` sería de valor vacío y no el valor `0`, como indica el título de la pregunta.

Answer (score 9):

Primero tienes que convertir el tipo Pais a `List<SelectListItem>` para poder mostrar los datos en el `SelectListItem`:

```
// lo convertimos a lista
var paises = db.Pais.Select(x=> new SelectListItem{ Text = x.Nombre, Value = x.Id}).ToList();
```

Luego inserta un elemento al inicio de la lista que tendra el texto que esperas utilizando el metodo [`Insert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
// insertamos el elemento en la primera posicion:
pais.Insert(0, new SelectListItem{ Text = "-- SELECCIONE --", Value = "0" });
```

Y luego continua con lo que ya tienes:

```
ViewBag.VBPais = pais;
```

Y en tu vista:

```
@Html.DropDownList("VBPais", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.VBPais);
```

Comment: esta bueno solo esto mas. [captura de pantalla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3GDR.png)

Comment: @R.Fernandez para eso usa un toString()

Comment: @R.Fernandez tienes que convertirlo a string IdPais.ToString()

Answer (score 7):

prueba agregando los siguientes parámetros:

```
@Html.DropDownList("VBPais", null, "Seleccione un país")
```

Comment: @R.Fernandez me corrijo, no había leído el título. Al usar de esta manera involucra que el valor por defecto sería vacío.

Comment: Asi mismo es y en parte debería ser así puesto que si se le asigna valor 0 a una opción del select pasaria como parámetro al controlador ese 0 y la validación la vería como válida cuando en realidad no lo es ya que no existe país con Id 0 en BD

Answer (score 3):

Es bien sencillo, sin necesidad de agregar opciones a tu lista, o por javascript. El truco está en el tercer parámetro del método de extension DropDownList:

```
@Html.DropDownList("VBPais", ViewBag.VBPais as SelectList, "-- SELECCIONE --", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Con la nota que te hace por ahí, donde dicen que la opción tendría un valor vacío y que termina ayudándote por ejemplo en validaciones. Te resultaría un select-option así:

```
<select class="form-control" id="VBPais" name="VBPais">
  <option value="">-- SELECCIONE --</option>
  <option value="1">VALOR1</option>
  <option value="2">VALOR2</option>
  <option value="3">VALOR3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Así mismo es Kodiak, e incluso el segundo parámetro puedes dejarlo en null como lo he definido puesto que (ViewBag.VBPais as SelectList) que has puesto como segundo parámetro ya lo has declarado sin darte cuenta en tu controlador con ViewBag.VBPais = new SelectList(db.Pais, "IdPais", "Nombre"); por lo que tu Helper ya sabe que necesita, en este caso "VBPais".

Comment: @VicenteAlmea Interesante, no me había dado cuenta de esa forma de relacionar el SelectList con el DropDownList. Gracias.